# AVD black screen with debugger detached

Tags: android, eclipse

I develop an application in eclipse and get stuck with this problem. When I run my AVD, it get stuck with the black screen as the following image.

[image]

In the logcat view, it shows "Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries"

[image]

I only start an MVD, haven't run my application yet. My MVD information is shown as following image.

[image]

Is anybody can figure out what happens with my Eclipse. I cannot continue my work. Thank you for all of suggestion or solutions.

Ps. I tried to create a new AVD but it does not work.
Ps. I already restart Eclipse.

[EDIT]
I run again and got this error.

[image]

Comment: If you dont need to test under 4.1 or have ARM specific code I'd just jump to Genymotion. Its worlds faster, seriously. Its faster than my Nexus 5.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is Genymonitor. @Mgamerz

Comment: Its an emulator that runs on VirtualBox and runs crazy fast. For personal use it is free.